# bash 4.4 inside python with os.system

Tags: python, bash, shell, os.system, bash4

I have problems with running a bash script inside a python script `script.py`:

```
import os
bashCommand = """
sed "s/) \['/1, color=\"#ffcccc\", label=\"/g" list.txt | sed 's/\[/    GraphicFeature(start=/g' | sed 's/\:/, end=/g' | sed 's/>//g' | sed 's/\](/, strand=/g' | sed "s/'\]/\"),/g" >list2.txt"""

os.system("bash %s" % bashCommand)
```

When I run this as `python script.py`, no `list2.txt` is written, but on the terminal I see that I am inside `bash-4.4` instead of the native macOS bash.

Any ideas what could cause this?

The script I posted above is part of a bigger script, where first it reads in some file and outputs `list.txt`.

edit: here comes some more description
In a first python script, I parsed a file (genbank file, to be specific), to write out a list with items (location, strand, name) into `list.txt`.
This `list.txt` has to be transformed to be parsable by a second python script, therefore the sed.

`list.txt`

```
[0:2463](+) ['bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I']
[2464:3397](+) ['Homoserine kinase']
[3397:4684](+) ['Threonine synthase']
```

all the brackets, `:`, `'` have to be replaced to look like desired output `list2.txt`

```
    GraphicFeature(start=0, end=2463, strand=+1, color="#ffcccc", label="bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I"),
    GraphicFeature(start=2464, end=3397, strand=+1, color="#ffcccc", label="Homoserine kinase"),
    GraphicFeature(start=3397, end=4684, strand=+1, color="#ffcccc", label="Threonine synthase"),
```

Comment: This looks much more complicated than it needs to be. What are you actually trying to do? At the very least, you should be able to reduce this to a single call to `sed`, using multiple `-e` arguments, and handling the output redirection with `subprocess.call`.

Comment: `with open("list2.txt", "w") as fh: subprocess.call(["sed", ...], stdout=fh)`

Comment: @chepner I know I should be able to reduce that or even implement in python, but I am not unfortunately...

Comment: Hence, me asking for a description of what you are trying to accomplish, so that I can suggest a pure Python solution. What's the input and expected output?

Comment: @chepner post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file in Python, parse each line with a single regular expression, and output an appropriate line constructed from the captured pieces.

```
import re
import sys

#                         1     2                3
#                        ---   ---              --
regex = re.compile(r"^\[(\d+):(\d+)\]\(\+\) \['(.*)'\]$")
# 1 - start value
# 2 - end value
# 3 - text value
with open("list2.txt", "w") as out:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        m = regex.match(line)
        if m is None:
            print(line, file=out)
        else:
            print('GraphicFeature(start={}, end={}, strand=+1, color="#ffcccc", label="{}"),'.format(*m.groups()), file=out)
```

I output lines that don't match the regular expression unmodified; you may want to ignore them altogether or report an error instead.

Comment: `print(line, file=out) SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I assumed Python 3; add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your file to make it work in Python 2.x (assuming you aren't using a truly ancient version of Python).